# How to give background image to cover whole page in Blackberry OS6 Torch device using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I am developing an app in Blackberry using phonegap. I am using jquery mobile1.2.0 for UI design.  Question is, where to give background image so that it covers whole page. What is happening is, the image is not covered to the whole page in the app, but I get the same for whole page in browser. Why it is happening so or any other way I can get the image for while page?CSS I have writter for background image is:

```
 .ui-mobile, .ui-mobile .ui-page {
    background-image: url("images/img_bg.jpg") !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: 100% 100% !important;
  }
```

Comment: Ya tried that also..doesn't work:(

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, it uses CSS3-
CSS3 support is available to Blackberry browser - http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts

```
.ui-mobile, .ui-mobile .ui-page  { 
       background: url('"images/img_bg.jpg"') no-repeat center center fixed;
       background-size: cover;
}
```

**OR**

You can use - http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Comment: Actually what you have suggested is working in desktop browser and even in Blackberry browser but it doesn't work in app.

Comment: There maybe other dependency in your app.Try to put !important.

Comment: Yeah I got it working by including height=device-height in meta tag:)